# What is the difference between / and ~/ relative paths?

Tags: asp.net, html, relative-path, relative-url

I thought that both types would bring you to the root folder, but apparently, they work differently, once you do a URL rewrite.

For instance, I normally use / which I know will bring you to the root folder and it does when a URL has been rewritten.

When someone else tried to use ~/ after a URL has been rewritten, then the path fails to find the file. Why is that?

Comment: Where is that used exactly? `example.com/~/`? In rewrite rules? In file paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/ will take you back to the root of your website.

~/ will take you to the home folder of your application on the website.

If your application is in a folder called myApp, for example, so the URL looks like this

```
http://www.YourSite.com/myApp/
```

and in your application you use ~/Scripts/jquery.js then the path referenced will be

```
http://www.YourSite.com/myApp/Scripts/jquery.js
```

whereas just using / would send you all the way back to the root of the website

```
http://www.YourSite.com/Scripts/jquery.js
```

Comment: Note that the `~/` URLs will only work when processed by ASP.NET.  You can call [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) on that URL, or use it in an `<asp:HyperLink />` or `<asp:Image />`, but just adding a `~/` URL into regular HTML isn't going to be transformed into the correct URL.  That is, the browser doesn't know anything about `~/` URLs, and won't be able to resolve them to the intended resource.