# What is the difference between Relative and Absolute paths in Aspnet MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This relative and absolute paths always confuse me. i want to know how and where to use them in Asp Net MVC.

For Ex- If i want to use a img tag-

```
img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/logo.png")" alt="Koiak Basic Site" />

img src="/Content/themes/base/images/logo.png" alt="Koiak Basic Site"/>
```

Kindly explain the difference between both of them

Comment: dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/q/317315/853295

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Absolute Path:**

An absolute URL path. An absolute URL path is useful if you are referencing resources in another location, such as an external Web site.

```
<img src="http://www.contoso.com/MyApplication/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

**Relative Path:**

A site-root relative path, which is resolved against the site root. Site-root relative paths are useful if you keep resources that are used throughout the site, such as images or client script files, in a folder that is located under the Web site root.

The following example path assumes that an Images folder is located under the Web site root.

```
<img src="/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

For More Refer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

*Coming to your Question:*

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/logo.png")" alt="Koiak Basic Site" />
```

Here because of using "~".It adds "server" path(i.e; your application path)" to your url. That means it takes `img src` as "yourapplicationPath/Content/themes/base/images/logo.png"

```
<img src="/Content/themes/base/images/logo.png" alt="Koiak Basic Site"/>
```

Here it takes as it is. i.e;"/Content/themes/base/images/logo.png"

For more refer this:

[why use @Url.Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515650/why-use-url-content)

http://digitalzoomstudio.net/2012/04/01/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-paths-urls/

[What is the difference between / and ~/ relative paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087606/what-is-the-difference-between-and-relative-paths)

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute Path**

*In terms of directory*

When we refer to a location from root like C:\Documents\MyFolder, it is absolute path.

*In terms of URL*

Absolute paths are called that because they refer to the very specific location, including the domain name. The absolute path to a web element is also often referred to as the URL. For example, the absolute path to this is:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/posts/21670682

**Relative path**

*In terms of directory*

When we refer to a location relative where we currently are, it is called relative path. For example, say currently you are at Documents folder in C:\Documents, to refer to MyFolder you have two choices: Absolute (C:\Documents\MyFolder) or relative (\MyFolder).

*In terms of directory*

Relative paths change depending upon the page the links are on. There are several rules to creating a link using the relative path:

links in the same directory as the current page have no path information listed

```
filename
```

sub-directories are listed without any preceding slashes

```
weekly/filename
```

links up one directory are listed as

```
../filename
```